# Hdinsight Spark Session issue with Parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

Using HDinsight to run spark and a scala script.
I'm using the example scripts provided by the Azure plugin in intellij.

It provides me with the following code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Fair enough. And I can do things like:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("wasb:///HdiSamples/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv")
```

and I can save files:

```
rdd1.saveAsTextFile("wasb:///HVACout2")
```

However, I am looking to load in a parquet file. The code I have found (elsewhere) for parquet files coming in is:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("resources/Parquet/MyFile.parquet/")
```

Line above gives an error on this in HDinsight (when I submit the jar via intellij).

Why don't you use?:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local[*]") // adjust accordingly
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "E:/Exp/") //change accordingly
  .appName("MySparkSession") //change accordingly
  .getOrCreate()
```

When I put in spark session and get rid of spark context, HD insight breaks.
What am I doing wrong?
How using HdInsight do I go about creating either a spark session or context, that allows me to read in text files, parquet and all the rest? How do I get the best of both worlds

My understanding is SparkSession, is the better and more recent way. And what we should be using. So how do I get it running in HDInsight?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I add

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark SQL basic").getOrCreate()
```

After the spark context line and before the parquet, read part, it works.